# Clearing a text field if nothing is submitted

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, textfield

I don't know if this is even possible, but in my rails app, I have this currently to put text in a text_field to be a description instead of having an external label:

```
      <% inside = "Search for Customers" %>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search],
                         :style => "color:#aaa;",
                         :value => inside, #defined above
                         :onfocus => "if(this.getValue()=='#{inside}'){this.clear();this.style.color = '#000';}",
                         :onblur => "if(this.getValue()==''){this.setValue('#{inside}');this.style.color = '#aaa';}" %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
```

This works great, but if I don't enter anything in, it searches for "Search for Customers", which is not what I intended. Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks

Edit:

I've added a `:onSubmit => "if(this.getValue()=='#{inside}'){this.clear();}"` to the text_field_tag, but it's still not doing anything. I've also tried `:onbeforesubmit` and even a simple `alert('test')` but it's not working for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

There is a new placeholder attribute for inputs in HTML5, it does exactly what your asking for, but wont work for everyone yet.

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/detect.html#input-placeholder

You could use it and fallback to populating and clearing the field with the onsubmit event for people that have older browsers.

Comment: I'd rather not use HTML5 as I'm pretty sure 95% of my users won't be using modern browsers (unfortunately). Also, I tried the onSubmit thing, but it's not working :\ (see my edit in the OP)

Comment: Did you put the onsubmit on the form or the input?

Comment: I think I need to put it on the button, but I'm not sure how to clear something in the text field from the button before it's submitted.

Comment: Ok, I think it would probably have to be on the form.

Answer (score 1):

You may also simply ignore the request at the controller level if the search field is blank or if the search parameter corresponds to your `inside` string, something like:

```
def search
  if params[:search].blank? || params[:search] == "Search for Customers"
    return
  else
    do_whetever_you_want
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Fill inside by params[:search] if define

```
<% inside = params[:search] || "Search for Customers" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if rails makes it different, but you can usually use:

`<form onbeforesubmit="someFunction()">`

And then in somefunction() clear the textfield.